# escaping colon ":" in SpEL expression

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I am trying to build a url in a spring integration flow like shown:

```
<int:header name="url" expression="${gateway.protocol}+'://'+${gateway.host}+':'+#{systemProperties['integration-test.port']}?:${gateway.port}+'/'+${gateway.context}" />
```

however I continuously get the following error:

```
SpelParseException: EL1041E:(pos 9): After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: '':''
```

I have tried using \ and \\ and as you can see I have single quotes around it, which according the documentation here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html should be enough.

any help would be much appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need single quotes `'` around your placeholder(s)...

```
expression="'${gateway.protocol}'+'://'+'${gateway.host}'+ ...
```

Otherwise whatever they resolve to will be evaluated by SpEL.

Or...

```
expression="'${gateway.protocol}://${gateway.host} ... '"
```

Comment: Thanks this mostly helped, the biggest issue was the elvis operator mixed in the expression.  I eventually yanked it out and put it in a separate header enricher and used the header value in the expression above.  The final expression was "'${gateway.protocol}://${gateway.host}:'+ header['port'] +'/${gateway.context}'"