# SpelParseException in Springcloud data flow

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to deploy a springcloud data flow stream like this:

```
time | http-request --url-expression='http://mydomain.fake:1234/myservice?myparams=myvalues' | log
```

Versions used:

- dataflow=2.9.2
- skipper=2.8.2
- http-request= [3.2.0](https://maven://org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:http-request-processor-kafka:3.2.0)

But I have some troubles with the `url-expresion` param format. The stream partialy deploy, with exceptions in the `http-request` step.

```
>   Property: http.request.url-expression
>     Value: http://mydomain.fake:1234/myservice?myparams=myvalues
>     Origin: System Environment Property "SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON"
>     Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to org.springframework.expression.Expression (caused by
> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After
> parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the
> expression: 'colon(:)')
```

I'm sure that I'm using a bad format in the stream params, but I can't find the good way to write it.I tried it with **simple quote**,  **double quote** and **no quote**, and the exception is always the same. Any help please ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved ( I think so ) .
Its possible that the expression takes the colon like a ternary operator ( some like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25166951/escaping-colon-in-spel-expression) )

I replace the expression

```
--url-expression='http://mydomain.fake:1234/myservice?myparams=myvalues'
```

to

```
--url-expression='http://mydomain.fake'+':1234/myservice?myparams=myvalues'
```

and it works. Thanks !